# What open source database platform is most easily transferred from my personal machine into a windows server?

Tags: database, database-design, open-source

I would like eventual interaction with MS Dynamics SL and/or MindTouch Core (running on WMware) for eventual intranet and/or internet display.

Comment: Is there a programming question in there somewhere?

Comment: This is not a discussion site, it is a Q&A site on programming.  This means you must ask questions which are focused, programming-related and amenable to a definite answer.  Your question breaks all of these rules, not least because it is actually half-a-dozen questions.  If you ask a series of separate questions (new post for each one) you will probably get helpful answers.  But if you leave this question as it is, it will probably be closed without any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL, PostgreSQL are both valid, functional choices that interact well with ODBC based tools on the Windows platform.